# Is it fine to promote an Area51 proposal on any meta site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, per-site-meta

I am not much of a meta guy but I do understand that the meta sites are usually scoped to their related main sites.

I saw a proposal on Area51 and I liked it. Since there is a related existing SE site, I am thinking to start a meta discussion there so that the users there can follow and/or contribute the proposal, if they like.

I feel this is fine as this is just a meta post for discussion, but asking here for confirmation.

Of course, I wouldn't have promoted on a meta site if the new proposal wasn't related to it.

*Note: I understand if I have to discuss about the proposal I should do that on [Area51.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) itself.*

Comment: Actually, a separate meta post advocating for another proposal is, I imagine, rarer than Glorfindel's answer below paints it. There used to be Community Promotion ads, where advertising another site was commonplace, but I haven't kept track and don't think it's a thing anymore these days. Anyway, you should be safe enough focusing more on why it objectively might interest the users of the host site in your meta post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it is fine as long as the topic of the proposed site is relevant to the meta where you are promoting it, but:

**Don't post this as a "promotion", post it as a discussion.**

Would the existing site benefit from starting up the new site? How should the sites deal with overlapping scopes? In case the new site is a subset of the existing site, should posts regarding the subset be made off-topic on the existing site? And so on.

More cross-site discussions of this kind in general is a good thing, even between established sites, since there's a whole lot of sites with overlapping scopes.

Answer (score 10):

It might depend on the community where you intend to post this 'advertisement'; I can imagine there might be users who will be complaining that it draws people away from their site. But what you propose has some precedents around the network, e.g. this post on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Meta, asking to commit to the Area 51 proposal for what is now [Language Learners](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/):

[Please consider committing to the Language Learners proposal](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2983/18673)

Comment: +1 another example of sites helping each other is Travel users helping Expats through Area 51 and then to [meet the survival criteria](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/helping-out-our-sister-site-expats-progress-100-thanks-to-all-who-helpe?r=SearchResults). If two sites compete or duplicate in a bad way, rather than complement each other, then the proposal would probably be rejected anyway

Comment: What about language site promotion on a religious site?

Comment: To add more to Ankit Sharma's question, the language is stongly bound to the religion.

Comment: @Mr_Green That would be a really good example of synergy where sites complement each other. See for example this [post about a Hebrew proposal on Judaism meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/please-help-the-hebrew-language-usage-area-51-proposal) and this [post about a Semitic Languages proposal on Islam meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/semitic-languages-stackexchange-site), I'm sure there are more.